# JSON data text to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
var url1 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id='+chanID+'&key=AIzaSyCppVQFcUiLE8-Z2JSyjpvvek8WfPeCfcI';
                $.getJSON(url1, function(data){
                    $('#ytName').html('<a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/'+ data.items[0].snippet.customUrl + '\"> data.items[0].snippet.title)</a>');
});
```

I want to have a text that is also a Link. The text is fetched by JSON. What I have here won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `innerHTML` property to add the data

```
 $('#ytName').innerHtml('<a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/'+ 
       data.items[0].snippet.customUrl + '\"> 
                    data.items[0].snippet.title)</a>');
```

Comment: Am I missing something? What exactly is doing your interpolation?

Comment: The data wont load anymore

Comment: @DaniKemper thats what why? will it not load?